# Typescript strongly type void Function

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I'm trying to write an interface which takes a function in as a parameter:

Currently I'm trying this

```
export interface EditOptions {
     isEditing: boolean;
     save: () => {};
}
```

I've tried a few things to assign the function:

```
editOptions: EditOptions = { isEditing: false, save: this.save };
editOptions: EditOptions = { isEditing: false, save: () => { this.save() } };
```

Neither work instead I receive this error:

[image]

I Know that for now I can use `:any` but what is the proper way to strongly type a void function

Comment: Does the troll care to explain the down vote

Answer (score 3, accepted):

interface you can define as :

```
export interface EditOptions {
 isEditing: boolean;
 save: () => void;
 }
```

and you can use/assign it as :

```
editOptions: EditOptions = { isEditing: false, save: () => { this.anyFunction() } };
```

Comment: thanks for your quick response, I'll accept this answer when the time limit allows me

Comment: can you please mark this as answer , if it helped you to solve the problem,

Answer (score 5):

Hidden away from the docs [it exists](https://microsoft.github.io/PowerBI-JavaScript/interfaces/_node_modules_typedoc_node_modules_typescript_lib_lib_dom_d_.voidfunction.html) `VoidFunction`:

```js
interface Example {
 save: VoidFunction;
}

const example: Example = {save: () => { this.saveForReal(); } };
```

Comment: Bonkers it isn't documented elsewhere. Thanks for the link.